# Running a private tezos chain for development

Tags: sandbox

I never got the sandbox parts to work but I was able to create my own Tezos chain. I downloaded the source code, then changed the dictators public key to a key that I controlled. Then, after compiling and running the node, I could inject the protocol with my dictator's secret key:

```
tezos-client activate protocol Ps9mPmXaRzmzk35gbAYNCAw6UXdE2qoABTHbN2oEEc1qM7CwT9P with fitness 24 and key dictator and parameters ../mysandbox.json
```

After that I could do whatever I wanted with the bootstrap accounts I had in my JSON, bake, transfer, make new accounts, etc.

But now I can no longer bake. The protocol injection succeeds:

```
Injected BKn6EQc4ndGw
```

But tezos-client doesnt have the bake option anymore when I'm doing all this from scratch now.

Comment: Does `tezos-client list understood protocols` list the protocol you just activated?

Comment: before I inject on top of the genesis block that command shows: 
    Ps9mPmXaRzmz
    PsddFKi32cMJ
    PsYLVpVvgbLh
    PtCJ7pwoxe8J

and after I inject I get `Injected BMVZ56p8Z3v4` then running that list understood protocols again I get those same 4 protocols

Comment: When I want to activate the protocol it gives me an error saying :
Fatal error:
  "Assert_failure src/lib_client_base/client_keys.ml:237:6"
Dibyos-MacBook-Air:tezos heisenberg$ tezos-client list understood protocols

Answer (score 9):

> Disclaimer - i'm the author of the project below

I've put together a toolkit that allows you to run a locally sandboxed tezos chain for development, together with liquidity & tzscan preinstalled.

You can [check it out here](https://github.com/maht0rz/tezos-environment-manager).

If you have any questions, or the readme isn't clear, i'd be happy to clarify any details!.

Answer (score 6):

Which protocol is indicated in:

```
tezos-client -A <your-node> rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header
```

It is likely that it switched to protocol 002 (instead of 003), and that your client does not include the `bake` command for 002. It is hardcoded in the sources (since there were no votes at the time) that, after a given number of blocks, the node should switch to protocol 002 and then later to protocol 003.

Comment: At OCamlPro, we maintain our own branch of Tezos for the private networks that we deploy for our customers. We had to do many changes to make it work on the long time.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that with tezos-environment-manager (answer above) you have the `tezos-client bake for <alias>` command available at all times, due to the nature of the sanboxed client.

Comment: OK - Ive started from scratch again, recompiletd, etc.  After compilation, when I run the node, its genesis header shows protocol `PrihK96nBAFSxVL1GLJTVhu9YnzkMFiBeuJRPA8NwuZVZCE1L6i` and then I do the inject for protocol `Ps9mPmXaRzmzk35gbAYNCAw6UXdE2qoABTHbN2oEEc1qM7CwT9P` which succeded.  Then the head block which is level 1 shows its header as having `Ps9mPmXaRzmzk35gbAYNCAw6UXdE2qoABTHbN2oEEc1qM7CwT9P`

But this is actually what I expect though.  (right?)

Answer (score 2):

DUH:
    `tezos-client activate protocol PsddFKi32cMJ2qPjf43Qv5GDWLDPZb3T3bF6fLKiF5HtvHNU7aP with fitness 24 and key dictator and parameters ../mysandbox.json`